# How to select a single item in protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, selector, angularjs-e2e

Usually in protractor you can select singular element with:

```
element(protractor.By.css('#fdfdf'));
```

Occasionally you get something like this:

```
element(protractor.By.css('.dfdf'));
```

which potentially has more than one element. What's the correct way to select an index from a locator that locates multiple elements, and still contain the protractor's methods for sending Keys?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can get an indexed element from an array returned with

```
// Get the 5th element matching the .dfdf css selector
element.all(by.css('.dfdf')).get(4).sendKeys('foo');
```

Comment: This worked really well. Thanks. In case anyone else bumps into this and is wondering, get starts at 0, so to get the first element. `element.all(by.css('.dfdf')).get(0);`

Comment: If you're looking to get the first element, you could do `element.all(by.css('.dfdf')).first()` per their [documentation](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.first)

Answer (score 19):

If you want to get the first element then

```
element.all(by.css('.dfdf')).first();
element.all(by.css('.dfdf')).get(0);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one. It will work:

```
element.all(by.css('.dfdf')).get(4).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why xpath is so much underestimated but you can solve thousands of problems with it, including this one

```
let elem = element(by.xpath('(//div//a)[3]'))
```

You can specify the number of element to use. Keep in mind the numbers start from 1, not 0 as usually in js